# How to run dev url directly on Android or iOS Simlator

Tags: simulator

I have developed a mobile application using asp.net mvc3, jquery mobile,HTML5. Can anyone guide me regarding how to run the local development URL directly in the android or iOS simulator that would help me a lot in debugging the code and resolving the issues in various devices.

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 0):

iOS simulator is quite simple. Basically you need to run a local host using something like wamp, mamp, xampp. Once you have your local working, you should be able to open mobile safari in your simulator and hit the local for your site the same way you would do it in browser.

For Android though, I haven't had much luck getting the simulator to run with my local.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. But WAMP is for applications that are developed by using PHP and in my case I am using asp.net mvc3,jquery mobile,HTML5 for developing the applications. Can you please guide me more for running the dev local url directly in the iOS devices or android devices and debug the server side code.